# $.colorbox({href:"login.php"}); doesn't work when inside $(this).click();

Tags: jquery, href, colorbox

```
$.colorbox({href:"login.php"}); //this Works (opens login.php)

$(this).click(function(){
$.colorbox({href:"login.php"}); //Doesn't work (opens parent page after 5 sec and breaks colorbox)
}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, assuming that you copied and pasted the code, you're missing a paren. You should also call `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the link?/button? from doing what it's intended to do.

```
$(this).click(function(e){
    //Doesn't work (opens parent page after 5 sec and breaks colorbox)
    $.colorbox({href:"login.php"}); 

    //Prevent default so the button?/link? doesn't do what it's intended to do
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

No idea what `this` refers to in your scope but if it is an anchor or a submit button you might want to cancel its default action by returning false:

```
$(this).click(function() {
    $.colorbox({ href: 'login.php' });
    return false;
});
```